# Is there an official pattern for immutable (usually ConcurrentHashMap) data structure with ability for its replacement at intervals?

Tags: java, concurrency

I find myself repeating the code of

1. store **write only** copy of datastructure and read only **immutable ConcurrentHashMap**
2. readers are reading only from read only immutable HashMap **no locks**.
3. Writer are writing to write only data structure (another ConcurrentHashMap) with locks.
4. Every few minutes (depending on app needs) I switch the Read only datastructure which is a little old with the write only datastucture.  For this reason I use no locks here and I use a **volatile** only mark on the read only datastructure.

Is there an already published well know pattern with example code in java / official library which does that so that i don't have to create this pattern by myself?

Comment: I think what you are asking is to make an immutable snapshot of the contents of a ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: yeah :) is there something like that?

Comment: I searched today and didn't find such. Ended up wrapping my Scala `mutable.Map` within `synchronized`. Simpler in my case - ConcurrentHaspMap seems to be very performance oriented which is not important for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps I don't fully understand your requirement, but why don't you read and write to the one instance of `ConcurrentHashMap`? The whole point of a `ConcurrentMap` is that reading and writing to the maps between threads occurs in a thread-safe manner. Can you please explain why this can't occur in your case?

*Read only immutable ConcurrentHashMap* <-- this definitely doesn't make sense. Any `Map` instance that's safely published (eg a plain old `HashMap`), can be safely read by multiple threads. The only danger here is guaranteeing that the `Map` is only read from and not written to. That guarantee can be made by using either `Collections.unmodifiableMap()` or Guava's `ImmutableMap`. It's also worth mentioning that it's best to ensure that the map entries themselves are immutable.

Comment: there are more dangers for example the read only map must be volatile otherwise if you change the reference which points to the read only map not all threads might be aware of it.  exactly because of this additional risk and more (some of them well known some less) i'm interested in a well defined pattern.

Comment: @Jason I agree with what you're saying regarding safely publishing the reference to the map with volatile. However, I don't understand why you have separate write and read maps. In my experience, I've found that using a single-shared instance of a ConcurrentHashMap normally suffices. Perhaps you could paste some code that clearly demonstrates the requirement? Regarding a pattern for reading and writing, perhaps the ReadWriteLock class partly facilitates this?

Comment: Hi I have a separate read write because i'm not worried about the freshness of the data, so i allow myself to have a read only version of the data which is "lock free" no locks there! the only place i  need to lock is when i write to the data to the write only data structure. and once in a minute i replace the read only data with the write only data.

Comment: It makes sense when you want to share an emptyConcurrentMap() instance.